# Where is the leak in my NSXMLParser code?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, nsxmlparser

I have set up an NSXMLParser to parse through a Twitter feed, but I am getting memory leaks, and after sitting through using instruments about a hundred times I can't figure out where it is! Below is my NSXMLParser code that parses when ASIHTTPRequest receives data back.

```
-(void)ProcessAndParse{

    NSURL *url = [config urlForFeed:@"Twitter"];
    ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request setDelegate:self];
    [request startAsynchronous];

}

- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
    NSData *responseData = [request responseData];
   myparser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:responseData];
    [myparser setDelegate:self];
    [myparser setShouldResolveExternalEntities:YES];
    [myparser parse];



}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    currentElement = [elementName copy];
}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName{


}

-(void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser{


}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string{




}
```

I know there is quite a bit missing here but I am trying to stop this leak before I go on any further. It seems to center around the `currentElement = [elementName copy];`in the didStartElement method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to release the previous element, before assigning a new one for currentElement, otherwise the old element won't have any other references and it will be leaked. So you can do this:

```
[currentElement release];
currentElement = [elementName copy];
```

Alternatively you can declare your ivar currentElement property as copy, and simply do this:

```
//This releases previous value, and copies the new Value.

self.currentElement = elementName;
```

Comment: the currentElement is a ivar, to allow this i must set an @property? with what parameters?

Comment: Or alternatively, use the keyword retain for that property, and remove the copy. Can't really put all the code in a comment, so I am adding an answer.

Comment: @Perception, in that case it would be better to have the property be copy.

Comment: let me do some more testing! i'll be sure to tick the answer once i'm done :)

Comment: @MrPink see my updated answer, I think the second option is cleaner.

Comment: @Oscar - cheers bud, I added an answer because I really couldn't fit code into my comment, but your edit captures the fix the OP needs. I am upvoting.

Answer (score 1):

Based on  your comments in Oscar's answer, you have *currentElement* as a property of your delegate class. I see two problems in your code:

---

You are creating an XML parser and never releasing it. To solve that do this:

```
myparser = [[[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:responseData] autorelease];
```

---

You are leaking the *currentElement* property. To solve that do this:

In your header file make sure your property is defined with the retain keyword

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * currentElement;
```

In your implementation file, make proper use of your property

```
self.currentElement = elementName;
```

That should fix all issues.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are allocating memory for currentElement in didStartElement but I don't see any place where you release it. It also looks like you are allocating memory for the parser but not releasing it in requestFinished

Answer (score 0):

The code does seem incomplete. To take a stab in the dark, though, I see two allocations and no releases:

```
myparser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:responseData];
```

and...

```
currentElement = [elementName copy];
```

Both the alloc return a retained object, which you would need to release.